# LeetCode MergeTwoSortedLists21 Line 18: error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ListNode' to 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<int>'

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list

The following code compiles and works in VS 2022. It was constructed under a netcoreapp3.1 console application.

When copied into LeetCode, I receive the following error when the "Run Code" button is clicked:

Line 18: Char 48: error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ListNode' to 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList' (in **Driver**.cs)

Is LeetCode using an older C# version, which may be causing the error? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Solution {
    public LinkedList<int> MergeTwoLists(LinkedList<int> list1, LinkedList<int> list2) {
        
            LinkedList<int> answerList = new LinkedList<int>(); 

            LinkedListNode<int> list1CurrentNode = list1.First; // This is line 18, which is causing the error
            LinkedListNode<int> list2CurrentNode = list2.First;

            LinkedListNode<int> answerListNode = answerList.First;

          //  Console.WriteLine(list1.First.Value);
          //  Console.WriteLine(list2.First.Value); 
          //  Console.WriteLine(list1CurrentNode.Value);
          //  Console.WriteLine(list2CurrentNode.Value);


            if (list1.First == null && list2.First == null)
            {
                answerList = null;
                return answerList;  
            }

            if (((list1.First.Value == 0) || (list2.First.Value == 0)) && ((list1 == null || list2 == null)))
            {
                answerList.First.Value = 0;
                return answerList;
            }

            if (((list1 == null) || (list2 == null)) && ((list1.First.Value == 0 || list2.First.Value == 0)))
            {
                answerList.First.Value = 0;
                return answerList;
            }


            while (list1CurrentNode != null && list2CurrentNode != null)
            {
                if ((list1CurrentNode == list1.First && list2CurrentNode == list2.First) && (list1.First.Value >= list2.First.Value))
                {
                    answerList.AddFirst(list2CurrentNode.Value);
                    answerListNode = answerList.First;
                  //  Console.WriteLine(answerListNode.Value); 
                    answerList.AddAfter(answerListNode, list1CurrentNode.Value);
                  //  Console.WriteLine(answerList.First.Value);
                  //  Console.WriteLine(answerList.Last.Value);

                }

                else if ((list1CurrentNode == list1.First && list2CurrentNode == list2.First) && (list1.First.Value < list2.First.Value))
                {
                    answerList.AddFirst(list1CurrentNode.Value);
                    answerListNode = answerList.First;
                  //  Console.WriteLine(answerListNode.Value); 
                    answerList.AddAfter(answerListNode, list2CurrentNode.Value);
                  //  Console.WriteLine(answerList.First.Value);
                  //  Console.WriteLine(answerList.Last.Value);
                }

                else if (list1CurrentNode.Value >= list2CurrentNode.Value)
                {
                    answerList.AddLast(list2CurrentNode.Value);
                    answerList.AddLast(list1CurrentNode.Value);
                }

                else if (list2CurrentNode.Value > list1CurrentNode.Value)
                {
                    answerList.AddLast(list1CurrentNode.Value);
                    answerList.AddLast(list2CurrentNode.Value);
                }

                list1CurrentNode = list1CurrentNode.Next;
                list2CurrentNode = list2CurrentNode.Next;   

            }
            
           // Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", answerList));
            return answerList;
    
        
        
    
    

     
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
          LinkedList<int> firstList = new LinkedList<int>();
            LinkedList<int> secondList = new LinkedList<int>();

           firstList.AddFirst(5);
            firstList.AddLast(6);
            firstList.AddLast(2);
            secondList.AddFirst(7);
            secondList.AddLast(1);
            secondList.AddLast(9);
            
            
            Solution solution = new Solution();
            solution.MergeTwoLists(firstList, secondList);

            
        }
     
     
     
     
     }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing `using System.Collections.Generic` into LeetCode file?

Comment: Merna. I added using System.Collections.Generic to the leet code file, however I then received a warning CS0105: The using directive for 'System.Collections.Generic' appeared previously in this namespace (in Solution.cs) error

Comment: I had a look at the problem. the original problem has a `ListNode` as a return type, also the parameters have the same type. you should try to solve the problem with this type and don't change it otherwise, the LeetCode compiler will not recognize your solution.

Comment: Hi Merna, I had noticed that originally, however I think that is an error in the specification of the problem overall: Example 1 shows an output that clearly cannot be of type ListNode, within the bounds of the original problem (it could be if the ListNode were specified as an array of int's): [1,1,2,3,4,4]. Now that I'm reviewing the whole problem, what is being asked (return the head of the merged linked list) is somewhat clear, however the example outputs should be single integer list nodes, rather than the entire merged linked list.

Comment: You changed the signature of the function. You must use `ListNode`, not `LinkedList`. It is in the template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tested your code outside of Leet Code, but also changed the signature of the function. Leet Code presents the following template code:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     public int val;
 *     public ListNode next;
 *     public ListNode(int val=0, ListNode next=null) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.next = next;
 *     }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode MergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) {
        
    }
}
```

You are supposed to work with that. But in your code you are using `LinkedList`, both for the arguments and the return type. There is no hope that the Leet Code tests will pass when you change the data types.

To get you started, in your offline version, you should have driver code that looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ListNode firstList = new ListNode(5,
                         new ListNode(6,
                         new ListNode(2)));
    ListNode secondList = new ListNode(7,
                          new ListNode(1,
                          new ListNode(9)));
    Solution solution = new Solution();
    ListNode mergedList = solution.MergeTwoLists(firstList, secondList);
    // Output the returned result           
    for (ListNode node = mergedList; node != null; node = node.next) {
        Console.Write("{0} ", node.val);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```